# Excel VBA - Append cell by removing string

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am looking to append cells containing numbers and text so that the text is removed.

Take `1.1 (Very Low)` as an example of what is in the cell.

I would like to remove  `(Very Low)` from the cell.

Comment: VBA use `instr` for "(". But you can do this with `find` + `left`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this using `InStr`.

I was trying to edit cells in a range by cycling through them whilst checking for a string. I would then remove the specified string. You can do this by checking the cell for your string using `InStr` and then using `Replace` to update the cell contents.

I found a way to do this using:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet, rCell As Range, rArea As Range

    Set rArea = ws.Range("A1:A10")
    For Each rCell In rArea.Cells
        If InStr(rCell.Value, " (Very Low)") Then
            rCell.Value = Replace(rCell.Value, " (Very Low)", "")
        End If
    Next rCell
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `left` and `find`:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1,1)-1)
```

[image]

VBA:

```
Dim p As String
Dim loc
p = "("

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    loc = InStr(1, .Cells(i, "A").Value, p)
    .Cells(i, "A") = Left(.Cells(i, "A"), loc - 1)
Next

End With
```

Comment: I don't see how I can apply this as VBA to cells in a range. It also populates new cells with data, when I'm looking to append the original cells.

Comment: Edited to add VBA.